# Change Bootstrap modal video source dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video, bootstrap-modal

I have a db keeping videos `src` and some information about video.

I'm taking those variable by while loop and passing to `jquery` script but even though video's `src` attributes are correct, videos are not playing the new source link.

I used the code given in [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

[This is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/mvazpocw/1/) that I'm using in the page

```
<div class="pb-2 pr-0 col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" id="item">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-user="9GAG" data-link="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/1343598947286183946/vid/720x900/Jg8plRtix-yjzP6g.mp4">
    <img class="rounded" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1343598947286183946/img/_WUUCNjodgFAwfdw.jpg:thumb" alt="9GAG">
  </a>
</div>

**This is my Modal HTML**

<div id="myVideo">
    <video id="myVideo" width="1280" height="720" controls poster="" class="myvideo img-fluid">
        <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**This is JS**

```
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
       var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
       var link = button.data('link')
       var user = button.data('user')
       var modal = $(this)
       moda1l.find('.modal-title').text(user)
       modal.find('.video source').attr('src', link)
    })
```

I have searched topic for solution, there were some similar problems and solutions but as a rookie, I wasn't be able apply those solutions to my code. Thanks in advance for helps.

**--Edit After Solution--**
My final js code is like that:

```
//to pause the video if modal closed
$('#exampleModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
   let video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
   video.pause();
});
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
   var link = button.data('link')
   var user = button.data('user')
   var modal = $(this)
   modal.find('.modal-title').text(user)
   $('#myVideo source').attr('src', link)
   $('#myVideo')[0].load();
   //autoplay if modal opened
   $('#myVideo')[0].play();
})
```

Comment: the video source doesn't seem dynamic as the source value is coming from a data attribute in a button!

Comment: Hi, try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/adow2r5L/) using iframe .

Comment: @AhmadKarimi it comes from DB. For every thumbnail click it's posting a new soure to the script.

Comment: @Swati It (kind of) works with iframes but for every click creating a new reload. For example if you watch 5 videos, you have to click "Back" button five times go previous page. Also when modal closed, it continuous to play. Wouldn't be complicated to control iframe video to pause when click close or somewhere else to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for the source needs to change, and then load() the video...

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var link = button.data('link')
    var user = button.data('user')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(user)
    $('#myVideo source').attr('src', link)
    $('#myVideo')[0].load();
})
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/4fkR3vQDoI)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Also I've added to the last line $('#myVideo')[0].play(); to autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

Simple every changing for src should load the video , using media load [load(),](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load)
and if you want to start it on show just trigger [play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play) on video as following :

```
let video = $("#myVideo").get(0);
video.load();
video.play();
```

see working snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var link = button.data('link')
    var user = button.data('user')
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(user)
    modal.find('.video source').attr('src', link)
    let video = $("#myVideo").get(0);
    video.load();
    video.play();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container py-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="pb-2 pr-0 col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" id="item">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-user="KediOzelHarecat" data-link="https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/1346103833966088192/pu/vid/540x960/xXK63BN2krMPIdjw.mp4">
        <img class="rounded" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/ext_tw_video_thumb/1346103833966088192/pu/img/-gaHCYlnfVvdjmC4.jpg:thumb" alt="KediOzelHarecat">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-2 pr-0 col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" id="item">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-user="9GAG" data-link="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/1343598947286183946/vid/720x900/Jg8plRtix-yjzP6g.mp4">
        <img class="rounded" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1343598947286183946/img/_WUUCNjodgFAwfdw.jpg:thumb" alt="9GAG">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-2 pr-0 col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-xl-2" id="item">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-user="9GAG" data-link="https://video.twimg.com/amplify_video/1343598894937075723/vid/1280x720/vY1Ol_rQMw-jod60.mp4">
        <img class="rounded" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/amplify_video_thumb/1343598894937075723/img/sMJ2oEi3Iws6oCqM.jpg:thumb" alt="9GAG">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">User Screen Name</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body justify-content-center">
          <div class="video" id="divVideo">
            <video id="myVideo" width="1280" height="720" controls poster="" class="myvideo img-fluid">
              <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```